# Xcode9 could not launch"app"

Tags: xcode9

[Xcode could not launch my app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GPPll.png)

Today, I upgraded Python version 3.6, deleted the Python2.7 file, and I found that my Xcode9 couldn't be opened. I copied a Python2.7 file and a "current" file from my classmate. Then Xcode can open, but when running app, Xcode reminds me, "could not launch app", I tried a lot of ways, but can not find a solution. The simulator just shows the boot screen, and app gets stuck.
[APP launch Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J409M.png)

Answer (score 0):

OK，I found the way to solve my question.I found the Xcode problems was about the system Python version(2.7)，so I deleted my Python3.6,and reinstall Python2.7 by homebrew, configured the environment variables.And then the Xcode9 is working right.